# A faster Hessian vector product in PyTorch

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, autograd, hessian

I need to take a Hessian vector product of a loss w.r.t. model parameters a large number of times. It seems that there is no efficient way to do this and a for loop is always required, resulting in a large number of independent `autograd.grad` calls. My current implementation is given below, it is representative of my use case. Do note in the real case the collection of vectors `v` are not all known beforehand.

```py
import torch
import time

# Create model
model = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(1, 500), torch.nn.Tanh(), torch.nn.Linear(500, 1))
num_param = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())

# Evaluate some loss on a random dataset
x = torch.rand((10000,1))
y = torch.rand((10000,1))
y_hat = model(x)
loss = ((y_hat - y)**2).mean()

# Calculate Jacobian of loss w.r.t. model parameters
J = torch.autograd.grad(loss, list(model.parameters()), create_graph=True)
J = torch.cat([e.flatten() for e in J]) # flatten

# Calculate Hessian vector product
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    v = torch.rand(num_param)
    HVP = torch.autograd.grad(J, list(model.parameters()), v, retain_graph=True)
print('Time per HVP: ', (time.time() - start_time)/10)
```

Which takes around 0.05 s per Hessian vector product on my machine. **Is there a way to speed this up?** Especially considering that the Hessian itself does not change in between calls.

Comment: @Mocas thanks, I did not think of this. I did the same, but the answer does not make sense at all. One of the steps it gives to calculate the Hessian vp is... calculate the Hessian vp. Regenerating the response actually gave a more sensible answer, but I have tried the options it gave already.

Comment: Was my comment deleted? Wow!